# Export Excel Worksheets (from list of sheet names) to separete excel file with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want a VBA macro to export some Worksheets to a separate **xlsx** based on a list of sheet names. The list of these names are for example in the range **A1:A50 in Sheet1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation points to comment, so I can't determine what you require specifically. Hopefully you can get an idea from my answer.

I'll assume:

1. Each worksheet you want to export, is exported to its own (new)
   workbook (*.xlsx)
2. You will keep a copy of the exported worksheet in the current workbook

Note, this does not handle exceptions (like missing sheets, name mismatches, ...)

```
Sub ExportSheets()
    Dim wksWorksheets As Excel.Sheets
    Dim rngSheetNames As Excel.Range, rngSheet As Excel.Range
    Dim strSheetTitle As String, strSavePath As String

    strSavePath = "DriveLetter:\path\to\save\goes\here\"  ' Change this to your path
    Set wksWorksheets = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set rngSheetNames = wksWorksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50") ' Put the specific sheet and range here

    For Each rngSheet in rngSheetNames
        strSheetTitle = rngSheet.Value

        With wksWorksheets(strSheetTitle)
            .Copy
            .SaveAs Filename:= strSavePath + strSheetTitle + ".xlsx"
        End With

    Next rngSheet

End Sub
```

If this is not what you specifically need, it should not be to difficult to modify the code to your requirements.

njc

**Edit:**
To export to the same existing workbook. Note, the workbook must exist before exporting.

```
Sub ExportToWorkbook()
    Dim wkbExportBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wksWorksheets As Excel.Sheets
    Dim rngSheetNames As Excel.Range, rngSheet As Excel.Range
    Dim strSheetTitle As String, strWkBookPath As String

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strWkBookPath = "DriveLetter:\path\to\workbook\goes\here\ExportBook.xlsm"  ' Change this to your path
    Set wksWorksheets = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set rngSheetNames = wksWorksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50") ' Put the specific sheet and range here

    Set wkbExportBook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(strWkBookPath)

    For Each rngSheet In rngSheetNames
        strSheetTitle = rngSheet.Value
        wksWorksheets(strSheetTitle).Copy Before:=wkbExportBook.Sheets(1) ' Before the first sheet or any sheet you want, just pass the sheet index
    Next rngSheet
    
    wkbExportBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you require a new workbook for an export batch of sheets, look at the function,

```
Excel.Workbooks.Add strWorkBookPathName
```

You should be able to set this to a Workbook object variable.

njc

Comment: nice but it separates each one to single file, I want to collect all  of them in the same file

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy, I'll edit my answer for an existing workbook too

Comment: works very well, great job